# AngularJS updating scope in $http promise

Tags: angularjs

I am building an app that parses excel files browser side, then posts the data to Node. This is all working pretty well, but I am having trouble getting the file upload list to update when the scope is.

```
$scope.upload = function() {
    var files = document.getElementById('upload').files;
    var i, f;
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;

            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
                var sheetData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                if(sheetData.length > 0){
                    Sheet.create(f.name, sheetName, sheetData).success(function(sheet){
                        $scope.sheets.push(sheet);
                        console.log($scope.sheets);
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
}
```

'Sheet' is the sheet service, and the create method returns the result of the $http request. The correct sheets list (including the new one) is logged to the console, but the UI is not updated.

```
<div class="drive-item" ng-repeat="sheet in sheets | filter:query " >...</div>
```

Comment: Try to call apply after updating the scope

Comment: I tried both `$scope.apply()` which returns an undefined function error are well as `$scope.$apply()` which rootscope.inprog error.

Comment: I put it in the success function, directly after I pushed the new sheet onto sheets.

Comment: What is the filter in the markup doing? Are you sure that is working correctly? If your console log puts out the correct list, then `$scope.sheets` will be in synch - angular watch those changes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the update code in timeout. The reason you get the rootscope.inprogress error is because a digest was running when you called scope.$apply. So, inject $timeout (where you put $scope), then

```
// model updating code in async block
// ...
// end model updating code
$timeout(); // triggers digest safely
```

or

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) { // check if we are in digest
    $scope.$digest(); // run digest
}
```

will also call the digest safely

Comment: Don't do this. Having to use `$timeout` along with phase checking and then using `$digest` means you are doing something wrong. Using a hack to fix it will not help in the long run.

Comment: Angular is not perfect, sometimes you have to break their notion of model first to get what you want. It's stupid to say you can never break the rules. The framework is there to serve you, not the other way around.

Comment: Sure, but this is a simple case of dealing with a-synch scope updates - it's been done a million times and is almost the ideal use case for angular. If he cannot get it to work, his code is not making correct use of the tools at hand.